# Keeping an image file or Importing a package to get the image is expensive flutter

Tags: flutter, icons, font-awesome, flutter-assetimage

I am figuring out which one is more **storage friendly** when it comes to getting some icons which are not available in the flutter icons module.

So, there are two ways to do it

- Get your icons as `assets`, store in the app, and then use it wherever you want
- Get a package, in my case, [font_awesome_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/font_awesome_flutter), which practically has the required icons. And then use the icon via this package after importing it.

I am wondering which one should I prefer, first one or second?

Note: I am not bothered about the process, but I care about the space it takes in the app, which eventually affects the app's size.

Comment: Unless you are using a very large number of icons, the space difference honestly isn't that much. In actuality, I think storing your icons as assets might be more space efficient as you are adding only the icons you use to your project. But, getting a package is more convenient. It really comes down to your preference in the end

Comment: Convenience wise I agree with you. But was looking for the space efficient thing. Thanks @Crazzygamerr, indeed a useful advice :)